# how to redirect logoff and login to another controler and action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have changed default route config to another controller and action like below

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Products", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             namespaces: new string[] { "WebStore.Controllers" }
        );
```

before:

```
 controller:Home
 action:Index
```

and now:

```
  controller:Products
   action:Index
```

now after login and logoff it goes again to (Home/Index) while i want it goes to

```
Products/Index
```

Comment: You need change from AccountController
you have 2 function LogOff() and Login

Comment: Please provide more code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to tell your login and logoff actions where to go next.

You can simply do:

```
public ActionResult login(string username, string password)
{
 // your login code
 return Redirect("/");
}

public ActionResult logoff()
{
 // your log off code
 return Redirect("/");
}
```

or if you use subdomain you could tell it to redirect to the specific route:

```
return RedirectToRoute("Default", new { controller = "", action = "" });
```